# How do I change numericupdown value using keys to take effect?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   CloudEnteringAlert.tolerancenum = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
   pictureBox1.Image =CloudEnteringAlert.CloudsOnly(bitmapwithclouds,bitmapwithoutclouds);
}
```

When I use the mouse to change the `numericupdown` value I see the effect on the `pictureBox1` image. But if I type another value in the numericupdown, why doesn't it change anything in the `pictureBox`; doesn't get affected when I change the value manually with the keyboard ?

Comment: Did you press `Enter` or navigate to another control after entering the value? This is necessary for the ValueChanged-event to be fired.

Comment: The event is fired but thr effect on the value changed is happen only when i use the mouse and move the arrows down up but it dosent take effect when i use the keyboards to enter numbers manualy.

Comment: I checked it again now and i found that the problem is when i type any value in the numericupdown using the keyboards keys and mouse cursour is in/over the numericupdown area it dosent make any effect on the pictureBox dosent change anything but once i move the mouse away from the numericupdown area its changing and take effect. Why is that ? And how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

Solution was to use also Textchanged and not only ValueChanged:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            numericUpDown1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(numericUpDown1_TextChanged);
        }

        void numericUpDown1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CloudEnteringAlert.tolerancenum = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
            pictureBox1.Image = CloudEnteringAlert.CloudsOnly(bitmapwithclouds, bitmapwithoutclouds);
        }
```

Comment: if this is the answer to the question please click on the accept button so others know this is the solution

Answer (score 0):

> Use KeyUp event for Numeric updown.
>
> And in KeyUp event, get the value by

```
string str = numericUpdown1.Text;
```

Answer (score -1):

You must Press enter key or move to other control OR Add a Key_Up/Key_Down/Key_Press event

```
 private void numericUpDown1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(this.numericUpDown1, new EventArgs());
    }
```

Comment: The `KeyDown` or `KeyPress` is a character late to get the actual value of `NumericUpdown`, you should suggest the OP to use the `KeyUp` only, for example, if user types `12`, the value you get in the `KeyDown` or `KeyPress` is just `1`, while in the `KeyUp`, it's exactly `12`.

Comment: KeyUp will fire every after a character is press in the keyboard